# Externalize Kendo UI module from Angular app

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, ngx-build-plus

I'm using ngx build plus and trying to externalize a Kendo module, like Kendo Angular Buttons. Issue I'm running into is the Kendo UI library does not have a .umd file (its not an Angular library project). And I have externalized successfully with projects that have .umd files.
So I'm trying to use the main.js file available in the kendo-angular-buttons module when externalizing by copying it into the src/assets dir, but my angular main.js file is not able to find the kendo-angular-buttons.
My question is - is there a way to use .js file when externalizing using ngx-build-plus?